# Slide up and fade in animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to create an animation in CSS or JS simmilar to this:http://oshinewptheme.com/v29/

So when the user scrolls down onto the image it rises up slightly and fades in.I have created the base structure for this:

## HTML

```
<body>
<div class="gallery" align="center">
<img src="1.jpg">
<img src="3.jpg">
<img src="4.jpg">
<img src="5.jpg">
<img src="8.jpg">
<img src="9.jpg">
</div>
</body>
```

## CSS

```
.gallery{
    align-content: center;
    margin-left: 200px;
    margin-right: 200px;
    margin-top: 500px;
}
```

I am not sure on how to get the animation working if you have any ideas it would be great here is the project:https://codepen.io/Hamzaw_GD/pen/zRQxZo

Thank you very much in advance I am only 13 and very desperate for a solution so please be patient with me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other answers referred to the hover overlay or general animation, but I thought you were especially interested in having the images fade in and move up once you scroll down.

This does the trick. I've commented on the JS. Beware, it uses jquery. Let me know if you have questions.

```js
$('.gallery img').addClass('hidden');

$(window).on('scroll', function(){

// Get the vertical offset of the first gallery image that is hidden.
var p = $('.gallery .hidden').offset();
p = p.top;

// Check for the current scroll position.
var s = $('body').scrollTop();
  
// Get the height of the window.
var h = $(window).height();

// Just logging the results for better understanding.
console.clear();
console.log(s + h, p);
  
// Triggering the fade in when the image is partially reached by scrolling (in this case 100px)
if((s + h) >= p) { 

// Find the first element within <gallery> that has the class 'hidden'. Then fade it in by adding the class 'fadeIn' and removing the class 'hidden' so it is taken out of the rotation.
$('.gallery').find('.hidden').first().addClass('fadeIn').removeClass('hidden');
}
  
else {}
});
```

```css
.gallery {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right:auto;
  margin-top:100vh;
    max-width:600px;
  position:relative;
}

.gallery__help {
  text-align:center;
  transform: translateY(-50vh);
}

.gallery img {
  opacity:0;
  max-width:600px;
}

.hidden {
  transform: translateY(100px);
}

.fadeIn {
  opacity:1 !important;
  transform: translateY(0);
  -webkit-transition: all 2s ease;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="gallery">
  <p class="gallery__help">Please Scroll Down</p>
<img src="https://media.springernature.com/full/nature-static/assets/v1/image-assets/531S56a-i1.jpg">
<img src="http://www.samoaobserver.ws/images/cache/600x400/crop/images%7Ccms-image-000009332.jpg">
<img src="http://www.worddive.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/nature-and-environment-course.jpg">
<img src="https://cmkt-image-prd.global.ssl.fastly.net/0.1.0/ps/4037855/300/200/m2/fpc/wm0/ofj73imzdnhtoxcvlmowaxbdmbbtf2yixqwhacy3wwsjctvxybw0ggbjs9y7hr1h-.jpg?1519205483&s=10ea078a417885590d11783ca8a43b52">
<img src="https://lucysmagazine.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/Screen-Shot-2017-04-01-at-8.58.36-AM.jpg">
<img src="http://img.fotocommunity.com/alte-hoehenburg-9eebdd0f-f85d-40d7-9944-c15672ca0242.jpg?height=400">
</div>
```

Comment: Hello is it possible if you make it in the same arrangement as I have and thank you so much!

Comment: thanks! I'm not sure what you mean by "same arrangement". Here's the codepen: https://codepen.io/ingostahl/pen/qxGEvY

Comment: could you please 1+ my question and i meant as in two images in one row and then another two in the next row and one in the second last row and the last one in the last row

Answer (score 1):

Try the [animate.css](https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/) library. Should help with what you need.

Comment: how do I do this?

Comment: no problem. have fun! just download it, copy the class you want and add it to your stylesheet. Add the class to the image tags that you want to slide up and fade in.

Answer (score 1):

This is the quick and easy solution.

```css
 .gallery{
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
  max-width:600px;
 }
 IMG      {width:100%; max-width:500px;}
 IMG:hover{width:110%; max-width:550px;}
```

```html
<div class="gallery" align="center">
<img src="https://media.springernature.com/full/nature-static/assets/v1/image-assets/531S56a-i1.jpg">
<img src="http://www.samoaobserver.ws/images/cache/600x400/crop/images%7Ccms-image-000009332.jpg">
<img src="http://www.worddive.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/nature-and-environment-course.jpg">
<img src="https://cmkt-image-prd.global.ssl.fastly.net/0.1.0/ps/4037855/300/200/m2/fpc/wm0/ofj73imzdnhtoxcvlmowaxbdmbbtf2yixqwhacy3wwsjctvxybw0ggbjs9y7hr1h-.jpg?1519205483&s=10ea078a417885590d11783ca8a43b52">
<img src="https://lucysmagazine.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/Screen-Shot-2017-04-01-at-8.58.36-AM.jpg">
<img src="http://img.fotocommunity.com/alte-hoehenburg-9eebdd0f-f85d-40d7-9944-c15672ca0242.jpg?height=400">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

To achieve this you have to use CSS styles.

After every `img` element you have to add a `div` element with overlay styles and text.

```css
.gallery-item {
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.img-overlay {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: lightgray;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 4px;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.3s linear;
}

.gallery-title {
  height: 0;
  transition: all 0.3s linear;
}

.gallery-item:hover .img-overlay {
  opacity: 1;
}

.gallery-item:hover .gallery-title {
  height: 2em;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="gallery" align="center">
    <div class="gallery-item">
      <img src="https://media.springernature.com/full/nature-static/assets/v1/image-assets/531S56a-i1.jpg">
      <div class="img-overlay">
        <div class="gallery-text">
          <div class="gallery-title">FASHION MODELS</div>
          <div class="gallery-tags">Mobile, Web</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="gallery-item">
      <img src="http://www.samoaobserver.ws/images/cache/600x400/crop/images%7Ccms-image-000009332.jpg">
      <div class="img-overlay">
        <div class="gallery-text">
          <div class="gallery-title">FASHION MODELS</div>
          <div class="gallery-tags">Mobile, Web</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="gallery-item">
      <img src="http://www.worddive.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/nature-and-environment-course.jpg">
      <div class="img-overlay">
        <div class="gallery-text">
          <div class="gallery-title">FASHION MODELS</div>
          <div class="gallery-tags">Mobile, Web</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```